# Sum cells with same date and find average in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns:

```
Column A: Date
Column B: Value
```

I need to find the average of cells which summed up based on the same date. For example,

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPSeO.png)

Now I need an excel formula to sum the values with the same date and find an overall average. In the case of the above example, the output must be:

```
=SUM(55, 34, 65) -> 154
=SUM(35, 45) -> 80
=SUM(25, 64, 35) -> 124

=AVERAGE(164, 80, 124) -> 122.67
```

Can I have this result (122.67) from a single formula?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to be sure which you want, sum is not the same as average. Anyway both exist as sumif() or averageif() which means you can have dates as the criterion or sumifs() and averageifs() where you can have multiple criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(SUMIF(A2:A10,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A10,A2:A10<>"")),B2:B10))
```

[image]

(this is the average of 154, 80 and 124 not 164, 80 and 124)